# Convert date string swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a date string in this format:

```
2016-06-20T13:01:46.457+02:00
```

and I need to change it to something like this:

```
20/06/2016
```

Previously I have always used this library -> [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate/blob/master/Documentation/UserGuide.md) to manipulate the dates, but it doesn't work now.

I tried also something like:

```
let myDate = self.dateNoteDict[indexPath.row]!
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSxxx"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(myDate)
    print("date -> \(date)")
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The date format `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSxxx"` doesn't match the format of the string `2016-06-20T13:01:46.457+02:00`. For instance, where is the "T" in the date format?

Comment: I know but I can't find the right match

Comment: This document is very helpful: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lkYVY.png

Comment: You have to put your string in one line, and the format under it on the second line, and try to 'match' the format. For instance, the "hh" is for 12h format, but the string seems to handle 24h format, so "HH" instead, etc. Try this one: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`

Comment: @Larme it doen't work, date == nil

Comment: Vadian better explained below, however, thanks to everyone, +1

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The standard ISO8601 date format with fractional seconds and time zone is

> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

```
let myDate = "2016-06-20T13:01:46.457+02:00"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") // edited
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(myDate)!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let myDate = "2016-06-20T13:01:46.457+02:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // edited
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:myDate)!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from:date)
```

In macOS 10.13+, iOS 11+ `ISO8601DateFormatter` is an alternative as input formatter

```
let myDate = "2016-06-20T13:01:46.457+02:00"
let inputFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
inputFormatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate, .withFullTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:myDate)!
let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
outputFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
outputFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from:date)
```

Comment: It works. Thanks for help and for the explanation. +1

Comment: NSDateFormatter() is deprecated since Swift 3

Comment: This conversion gives me the date in UTC, i want to convert it into  my local date

Comment: For fixed date formats you need to set the date formatter locale to "en_US_POSIX"

Comment: If you're working with fixed-format dates, first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is en_US_POSIX, a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results **regardless of both user and system preferences**. en_US_POSIX is also invariant in time (if the US, at some point in the future, changes the way it formats dates, en_US will change to reflect the new behavior, but en_US_POSIX will not), and between platforms (works the same on iPhone OS as it does on OS X, and as it does on other platforms)

Comment: Resuming it might fail if the user uses 12h instead of 24h time format

Comment: This is a perfect solution and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

I always use this code while converting `String` to `Date` . 
(**Swift 3**)

```
extension String
{
     func  toDate( dateFormat format  : String) -> Date
    {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self)
        {
            return date
        }
        print("Invalid arguments ! Returning Current Date . ")
        return Date()
    }
}
```

and just call like . .

```
print ( "2016-06-20T13:01:46.457+02:00".toDate(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") )
//Capital HH for 24-Hour Time
```

Comment: This will actually return now as a Date in case the date string parsing fails. You should change the return type to optional and return nil in case of failure.

Answer (score 1):

I always use this code while converting String to Date. (Swift 4.2)

```
    let myDate = datePicker.date
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let date = myDate
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from:date)
    print(dateString)
```

You can try manually also:

```
    let myDate = "2019-02-22T08:21:11+0000"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let date = myDate
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from:date)
    print(dateString)
```